# como incrementar um array de objeto javascript em loop?

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, estou treinando meu javascript, mas estou com uma dúvida que não encontrei solução na internet, quero incrementar um array de objeto em loop, achei apenas como incrementar array, sendo objeto em loop não consegui solucionar, agradeço desde já.

```
var post = {
            teste: 'teste'
        };
        var i = 1;
        while (i <= countOption) {
            option = $('#options'+i).val();
            post.option+i = questionOption;
            i++;
        }
console.log(post)
```

esse é o código que estou testando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não estou no Pc

var post = {
teste: 'teste',
option: []
};

E depois:

post.option[i] = questionOption;

Comment: Obrigado cara, isso serviu pra mim, vlw mesmo